# Carpeta por defecto conexión FTP Python

Tags: python, ftp, filezilla

Cuando me conecto a una conexión por Filezilla se conecta a la raíz pero no se ve la carpeta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si especifico el nombre de la carpeta se conecta a esa carpeta sin problemas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando lo hago por Python (usando FTPLib) me indica que la carpeta no existe, he usado el comando `ftp.pwd()` y me lista la raiz (No se ve la carpeta que quiero) y utilizo `ftp.cwd('/Nombre_carpeta')` y me sale que la ruta no existe.
Tienen idea de que puede ser o como debo realizar la conexión desde python para que me funcione?

Comment: puede ser que no tengas permisos para ver dicha carpeta pero si el contenido dentro de la misma algo asi como darle permisos de `chown -R 777 /raiz/carpeta/*` cuando deveria ser  `chown -R 777 /raiz/carpeta`

Comment: Lo curioso es que con el mismo usuario que me conecto desde filezilla es el mismo con el que me conecto en Python, y en filezilla si veo la carpeta y en python no